# How can I condition circuitikz dots on a loop index?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm trying to use junction dots in circuitikz only on some iterations of a loop, but it fails.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily,
    every node/.style = {align=center}
]
\foreach[count=\i] \x in {0,3}
{
    \ifnum\i=1
    \tikzstyle{maybedot} = []
   \else
    \tikzstyle{maybedot} = [-*]
    \fi
     \draw (\x,0) to [R, l_={$R_\i$}, maybedot] (\x, 3) to [short, maybedot](\x,5);
}

     \draw (-2,0) to [R, l_={$R_0$ \\ noloop}, -*] (-2, 3) to [short, -*](-2,5);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

R1 correctly has no dots, but I want R2 to have dots like in R0. How can I get this to work? (my real example is more complicated and doing this sort of thing would save me a lot of repetitive code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your `\tikzset` (although using the old, best-avoided syntax) is setting the key `/tikz/-*` (an arrow), as you probably noticed in the errors:

```
prova.tex|20 error| Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind '*'.
prova.tex|20 error| Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind '*'.
```

The correct key for poles are `/tikz/circuitikz/-*`, so this works:

```latex
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily,
    every node/.style = {align=center},
    ]
    \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0,3}
    {
        \ifnum\i=1
            \ctikzset{maybedot/.style={}}
        \else
            \ctikzset{maybedot/.style={-*}}
        \fi
        \draw (\x,0) to [R, l_={$R_\i$}, maybedot] (\x, 3) 
            to [short,  maybedot](\x,5);
    }
    \draw (-2,0) to [R, l_={$R_0$ \\ noloop}, -*] (-2, 3) to [short, -*](-2,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Mixing `\if` things in `\foreach` loops is quite dangerous (although the problem was another one here). I'd use `\ifthenelse` here and a couple of macros instead of styles:

```latex
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[siunitx, american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily,
    every node/.style = {align=center},
    ]
    \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0,3}
    {
        \ifthenelse{\i = 1}{\edef\maybedot{}}{\edef\maybedot{-*}}
        \draw (\x,0) to [R, l_={$R_\i$}, \maybedot] (\x, 3) 
            to [short,  \maybedot](\x,5);
    }
    \draw (-2,0) to [R, l_={$R_0$ \\ noloop}, -*] (-2, 3) to [short, -*](-2,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you do not want to load `ifthen`, the test

```latex
\ifnum\i=1\edef\maybedot{}\else\edef\maybedot{-*}\fi
```

also works.

[image: out for the three possible options]

Comment: `edef` = ??? It's confusing that there's all these different commands with vaguely similar syntax, but each with their own semantics, and no clear way to look anything up in a reference.

Comment: `\edef` is expanded `\def`. It's core TeX, sorry --- in this case probably a normal `def` would work probably. Documentations is Knuth's TeXbook... ;-)